# Is it possible to integrate VichUploader in CKEditor?

Tags: file, symfony, ckeditor, vichuploaderbundle

I belive that i need some filebrowser for my application for using `image` button in CKEditor.
[image]

I have already install VichUploaderBundle for other thing. I know that [FMElfinderBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle) works perfect with CKEditor but maybe I don't need it if I have VichUploader. I try to browse server folder in search for images, but I am keep getting this error:

```
No route found for "GET 
/home/bartosz/andar/web/uploads/images/contentPhotos" (from 
"http://localhost:8000/admin/?
```

Here's part of my config.yml file:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        article_images:
            uri_prefix:         '%app.path.article_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.article_images%'
        content_photos:
            uri_prefix:         '%app.path.content_photos%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.content_photos%'

ivory_ck_editor:
    input_sync: true
    default_config: base_config
    configs:
        base_config:
            toolbar:
                full
        simple_config:
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.content_photos%'
            toolbar:
                - { name: "styles", items: ['Source','-','Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', 'Undo', 'Redo', '-''Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-','NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', '-','JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-','Image', 'Link', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', '-','Maximize']}
```

Comment: I have the same question, 3 years later